# how to parse the group of tags from xml in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Folks,

this is my xml response:

```
<parent>
<child>
<name>
<age>
</child>
<child>
<name>
<age>
</child>
...</parent>
```

i need to parse the each child content as xml string that:

**Output Needed:**

```
<child>
<name>
<age>
</child>
```

i have used normalize method also. but still i am facing problem to get a proper output.

my code is:

```
NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("child");// here documentobject is the Document of my xml.

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node element = nodes.item(i);
    // nodes.item(i).normalize();    
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: if you know what is sax... check out this tool: http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/sax-class-generator-v10.html

Comment: @Sherif: i am working on DOM parser.

Comment: this what i am getting in logcat "11-10 18:56:19.325: INFO/System.out(17645): org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl@405ef4e0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you want to use `getTextContent()` not `getNodeValue()`....

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("child");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {           
            if (nodes.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NodeList msgChildren = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < msgChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                    if (msgChildren.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element e = (Element) msgChildren.item(j);
                        System.out.println("<"+e.getNodeName()+">");
                        System.out.println(e.getTextContent());
                        System.out.println("</"+e.getNodeName()+">");                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this below Snippet :

```
        NodeList items_records = element.getElementsByTagName("child");
            for (int a = 0; a < items_records.getLength(); a++) {
                Node item_records = items_records.item(a);
                NodeList properties_records = item_records.getChildNodes();
                for (int b = 0; b < properties_records.getLength(); b++) {
                    Node property_records = properties_records.item(b);
                    String name_records = property_records.getNodeName();

                    try{
                        if (name_records.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                           parsed_total_records_value = property_records.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
                           Log.v("parsed_total_records_value",parsed_total_records_value);
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is to parse the name nodeValue. but my output will be like this " <name>venky</name><age>25</age>".

Comment: @SACPK If possible give your web link i will show you how to parse.